# mySQL inner join query - how do i combine these 2 queries?

Tags: mysql

This is my current query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.* FROM filter AS f
INNER JOIN filter_thread AS ft 
ON ft.filter_id = f.filter_id
INNER JOIN thread AS t 
ON ft.thread_id = t.thread_id
WHERE f.tag LIKE '%test%'
ORDER BY t.replystamp DESC
```

It returns a bunch of data including a "owner_id" column.

The 'user_table' contains a matching id, labeled, 'id'

I previously used this query to get the data:

```
SELECT username FROM users WHERE id='$user_id'"
```

I need these to occur in the same query! But adding an additional INNER JOIN is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

perhaps this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.*,u.username
FROM filter AS f
INNER JOIN filter_thread AS ft 
ON ft.filter_id = f.filter_id
INNER JOIN thread AS t 
ON ft.thread_id = t.thread_id
INNER JOIN users AS u
ON u.id = t.owner_id
WHERE f.tag LIKE '%test%'
ORDER BY t.replystamp DESC
```

Just a guess.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.*, u.username FROM filter AS f
   INNER JOIN filter_thread AS ft 
      ON ft.filter_id = f.filter_id
   INNER JOIN thread AS t 
      ON ft.thread_id = t.thread_id
   INNER JOIN users AS u 
      ON ft.owner_id = u.id
   WHERE f.tag LIKE '%test%'
   ORDER BY t.replystamp DESC
```

Comment: both worked like a charm. Can only accept one answer, so I will choose the first.